# Hide element if it has no children, but keep getting the previous children length

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I want to hide certain elements if there are no children. But I kept getting the previous children's length. How can I make the `resultLength` reflect the current children length?

```
  function pagiHide() {
    let resultLength = $(`[fs-cmsfilter-element="list"]`).children().length;
    if (resultLength == 0) {
      $('.pagination_wrapper').addClass('hide');
      console.log(resultLength);
      return;
    } else {
      $('.pagination_wrapper').removeClass('hide');
      console.log(resultLength);
      return;
    }
  }
```

At first, I tried the declare `reultLength()` outside of a function, but keep on getting the same length, then it kinda works when I declare it inside the function But the problem is I keep getting the previous length.

Comment: What's "the previous length"?   Do you mean if you call it twice it gives the same value?  Or the `.prev()` element's children?   Why/How would $("..").children().length` change value?   Can you provide enough (other) code/html to *recreate* the issue?   Sounds like you're making a change somewhere else and expecting this to change when that other change has no effect on this.

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me:

```js
function noChildHide() {
  $('.noChildHide').each(function() {
    const el = $(this);
    if (el.children().length === 0) el.addClass('hide');
    else el.removeClass('hide');
  });
}

noChildHide();
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="noChildHide">
  Div 1
</div>
<div class="noChildHide">
  Div 2
  <p>- Child 1</p>
  <p>- Child 2</p>
</div>
<div class="noChildHide">
  Div 3
  <p>- Child 1</p>
</div>
```

Also double check your selector and make sure it points to what you want to to point to.